# Указать путь к подключаемому файлу

Tags: php, require

Есть такая структура папок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно подключать файл included.php к другим файлам.
Подключил к parser.php:

```
require('included.php');
```

Всё хорошо.
Пытаюсь подключить этот же файл в SQLQueries.php:

```
require('../included.php');
```

Пишет ошибку, что такой файл не найден, при том, что PHPStorm видит этот файл.
Подскажите, что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 1):

может так попробовать

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(__ROOT__.'/included.php');
```

Comment: Почему мой вариант не работает?

Comment: возможно дело в самой функции require, я использую   include_once('../included.php');